# How to add a text after the name of function?

Tags: math-mode

I want to write a sentence like this:

```
f_{a}(x,y,t) some text here
```

But when I write like this there is no space between words.
How can I fix it?

Comment: `$f_{a}(x,y,t)$ some text here`. Did you read some introduction to TeX/LaTeX?

Comment: `$f_{n}(x) \mbox{ some text } g_{n}(x)` is one way. If the use of amsmath is made then use `\text{ some text }`

Comment: @egreg Do you want to answer that?

Comment: @Johannes_B Done

Answer (score 1):

Please, first of all consult a basic guide, for instance [Nicola Talbot's LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/) and don't disregard errors you get in compilation.

In line math formulas should be segregated in the `math` environment, which admits a shorthand:

```
Some text \(f_{a}(x,y,t)\) some other text
```